# Remove characters before reaching a set of wanted characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, character

I have this string coming from a virtual serial port with an ID/Passport reader:

b\0OU0IDBGR9247884874<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<|8601130M1709193BGR8601138634<3|IVANOV<

I have replaced the "/r" with "|" character.

The problem I would like to solve is always remove the characters before reaching the first combination of characters in the string which might be:
"ID","I<","P<" & "V<" "VI".

This is the issue at this stage I have tried the following to remove the characters but with no success:

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_' || c == '<' )
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: can you please show expected output too? (after the example input you give). i dont get this part `remove the characters before reaching the first combination of characters in the string which might be: "ID","I<","P<" & "V<" "VI"` so if you show expected result it may help.

Comment: “Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.” http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Thanks, I have missed that! With respect to the output it should be: 
IDBGR9247884874<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<|8601130M1709193BGR8601138634<3|IVANOV<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove the characters before reaching the first combination of characters in the string which might be: "ID","I<","P<" & "V<" "VI".

I think will do what you want.

```
string s = "b\0OU0IDBGR9247884874<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<|8601130M1709193BGR8601138634<3|IVANOV<";
s = string.Join("", Regex.Split(s, "(ID|I<|P<|V<|VI)").Skip(1));
```

First it splits the string on the character combinations you wanted (While preserving them in the resulting array - see the regex character group) and then discards the first member of the array (Which will be all the characters before the character combinations.) Then it joins the array together.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will try it out on Monday. And I will give you feedback! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sure it will work since my output is same as your desired output :)

Comment: Thank you once again, i think i will use it in another module as well!

Comment: Ok, finally I had time to test it. Strangely when I use this syntax 'string s = mySerialPort.ReadExisting().Replace('\r', '|');
                s = string.Join("", Regex.Split(s, "(ID|I<|P<|V<|VI)").Skip(1));
                Console.WriteLine(s);' it removes the character infron but since later it meets **IVANOV<** which is part of the regex it removes parts that are in front of the string. Any suggestions how to remove only character before the first met of such a combination?

Comment: excuse me for not mentioning the code correctly but it didn't give me the possibility to edit my comment and said I can only edit it in 5 minutes. :(

Comment: Uhm, I couldn't understand what you said. Could you show before and after strings in using your code?

Comment: before `b\0OU0IDBGR9247884874<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<|8601130M1709193BGR8601138634<3|IVANOV<` and after `IDBGR9247884874<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<V<`

Comment: I get `IDBGR9247884874<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<|8601130M1709193BGR8601138634<3|IVANOV<`.. Are you sure you have not altered the code in anyway?

Comment: `string s = mySerialPort.ReadExisting().Replace('\r', '|');
s = string.Join("", Regex.Split(s, "(ID|I<|P<|V<|VI)").Skip(1));
                Console.Write(s);`
I haven't change anything but it is possible that the serial port breaks the string and I don't get proper string, any suggestions?

Comment: What's the result of calling `mySerialPort.ReadExisting`?

Comment: Usually I get the string mentioned above `b\0OU0IDBGR9247884874<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<|8601130M1709193BGR8601138634<3|IVANOV<` but only when I say `Console.WriteLine(s);` if I use `Console.Write(s);` then I get it separated in a number of raws and they are not the same every time, maybe I can modify `mySerialPort.ReadExisting()` to get always the same output, maybe this gives errors. However when I use the `writeLine();` I always get the same output.